# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Multiple task action failures occurred:

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Help to solve this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpYfR.jpg)

Comment: This is some issue with peer dependencies. Do `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`and rebuild the app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.